# posting same answer to linked questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I posted a question on SO, and in the course of resolving the fundamental issue ended up posting two other questions, the last of which ([linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106321/how-to-use-a-dll-in-vba-without-registering-it?lq=1)) links back to the first two.  I've posted the solution, answering my own question, at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092273/what-arguments-does-updatelistitems-take-when-calling-sharepoint-web-service-fro/11125010); should I answer the other two with the same link, or leave them unanswered, as they link to an answered version of the core question?

Comment: Can you say "dog's breakfast?"  Meh, it's OK as-is; well wait and see if anyone complains.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can answer.

Because this linked questions are looking for different scenarios. You can answer that question according to requirement. Don't just post links of your answer. Give detailed answer and how it is best solution.